# Alterar linhas de um array - Python Pandas

Tags: python, numpy

Tenho um array e preciso alterar a ordem das linhas.

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Preciso dele assim:

```
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

Tentei usar o `.reindex` mas não tive sucesso, qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(25)
arr = arr.reshape(5,5)

print('array inicial:')
print(arr)

print('array com as linhas 0 e 1 trocadas entre si:')
```

Precisava fazer isso utilizando a biblioteca numpy

Comment: Se o seu programa cria primeiro a lista para depois inserir no array,  seria mais interessante tratar com list.pop() antes da inserção.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque as linhas diretamente:

```
arr[[0, 1]] = arr[[1, 0]]
```

---

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(25)
arr = arr.reshape(5,5)

print('array inicial:')
print(arr)

#Troca a posição das linhas 0 e 1 
arr[[0, 1]] = arr[[1, 0]]


print('array com as linhas 0 e 1 trocadas entre si:')
print(arr)
```

que resulta:

```
array inicial:
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
array com as linhas 0 e 1 trocadas entre si:
[[ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]
 [20 21 22 23 24]]
```

Código no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/FrontSlategreyParallelalgorithm)

Comment: Obrigado, deu tudo certo!

Answer (score 1):

Para efetuar essa troca, é possível indicar a ordem desejada das linhas em uma lista (ou tupla) diretamente na indexação do array:

```
arr = arr[[1,0,2,3,4],:]
```

Após ordenar:

```
In [14]: arr
Out[14]:
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

O resultado é uma **cópia** (e não uma visão) do array original com as linhas ordenadas.